# How to map and filter through array based on a value?

Tags: reactjs

How do i filter the data based on the id? Example if i wanted to filter id= "24". So it will filter out the object that is matching.

```
[
  {
    "id": "Sheet1",
    "data": [
      {
        "id": "24",
        "title": "Title of article",
        "date_time": "11/05/2022",
        "description": "Description of Article"
      },
      {
        "id": "25",
        "title": "Title of article 2",
        "date_time": "15/05/2022",
        "description": "Description of Article 2"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Output:

```
"data": [
      {
        "id": "24",
        "title": "Title of article",
        "date_time": "11/05/2022",
        "description": "Description of Article"
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter object array based on attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes) Have a look at [MDN docs for `filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I try this and i got the same output :

```
let arr = arrays.filter(array => array.id === "Sheet1");
let data = arr[0].data;
let result = data.filter(obj => obj.id === "24")
console.log(result)
```